# How to rotate object smoothly with slider in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, c#-3.0, unityscript, wsh

i am using a slider to rotate my object around its center and its working fine but my object moving so fast even i add speed,the slider value is between 0 and 1,Slider min value is 0 and max 1 and speed is 1, i want to rotate my object smoothly how i can do that please help me thanks
here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class RotateObject : MonoBehaviour {
public float speed =1f;
public GameObject ObjectToRotate;

public void RotateMyObject()
    {
    float sliderValue = GetComponent<Slider>().value;
    ObjectToRotate.transform.Rotate(sliderValue*speed*Time.deltaTime,0,90);
    }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `.Rotate()` function you can just set `.rotation` property with `Quaternion.Euler` to rotate your object smoothly using slider. Here is a sample code of mine:

```
public void RotateMyObject()
{
    float sliderValue = GetComponent<Slider>().value;
    ObjectToRotate.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(sliderValue * 360, 0, 90);
}
```

Comment: thanks with this code my object move smoothly but this code change the rotation angle of my object

Comment: Just place the sliderValue * 360 to the correct axis. Should do the trick.